# Using SharePoint PowerApps, How to add custom validation on List Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

In SharePoint Online, I have created a simple power app on a custom List. I want to add a validation on Title Column (Start with "Project -") on Form Submission. That is, user should not be able to submit the Form if Title column value doesn't start with "Project -". User should see an error and then they should modify the Title value and save again.

I found [Validate function in PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-validate/) link but 
unable to understand how to apply this to the form for my custom validation.

Please let me know how to add custom validations on list fields in Power App Form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found this [article](http://www.johnluangco.com/2016/11/PowerApps-Conditional-Formatting-Validation.html), meybe help you to achieve it

Comment: I guess you are trying to save the record with name concatenate with "Project" keyword !

Comment: unfortunately the article mentioned above does not help, because the question is about a List Form, not a normal Powerapp with SharePoint as a data source.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the OnSave event of the SharePointIntegration control for this. You can extend this event with a formula that checks if one or more conditions are fulfilled.

The steps are:

1) Select the SharePoint Integration Control

[image]

2) Go to the Advanced properties of the control:

[image]

3) change the OnSave formula (this is just an example, you can add your own formula):

[image]

Comment: thanks @Robert Wagenaar, you saved a lot of headaches  with your well explained solution !